# Does ENS have limited functionality on Goerli testnet?

Tags: nft, erc-721, ens, goerli

I just went through all the steps of purchasing and registering an ENS domain on the Goerli testnet. Process was similar to mainnet. However the token never appeared in my wallet with the name, just an ERC 721 that I guess represented it

Answer (score 1):

ENS has functionality. But it appears your wallet doesn't.

Comment: That may be it, I am using metamask. Is there any special steps that I must take to make it appear with the name on goerli testnet?

Comment: Also, I can't see the name via etherscan goerli either https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x143d8924606e90e922e796451af3a9fbd56caa06